Calculating an Inverse Matrix of a Matrix with variables
I am trying to understand a part of an article regarding quaternions spline interpolation, where the situation folded into the equation:
$$
(\vec{a}\cdot\hat{e})\hat{e}+\frac{\sin\Delta\theta}{\Delta\theta}(\hat{e}\times\vec{a})\times\hat{e}-\frac{1-\cos\Delta\theta}{\Delta\theta}\hat{e}\times\vec{a} = \vec{\omega_f}
$$
And the goal is to solve for $\vec{a}$, when $\hat{e},\Delta\theta,\vec{\omega_f}$ are known
Then a matrix B is defined, such that:
$$
B(\hat{e}, \Delta\theta)\cdot\vec{x} = (\vec{x}\cdot\hat{e})\hat{e}+\frac{\sin\Delta\theta}{\Delta\theta}(\hat{e}\times\vec{x})\times\hat{e}-\frac{1-\cos\Delta\theta}{\Delta\theta}\hat{e}\times\vec{x}
$$
So, in order to solve for $\vec{a}$, they use the inverse of $B$, such that:
$$
\vec{a} = B^{-1}(\hat{e}, \Delta\theta)\cdot\vec{\omega_f}
$$
Where:
$$
B^{-1}(\hat{e}, \Delta\theta)\cdot\vec{x} = (\hat{e}\cdot\vec{x})\hat{e}+\frac{\Delta\theta \sin\Delta\theta}{2(1-\cos\Delta\theta)}(\hat{e}\times\vec{x})\times\hat{e}+\frac{1}{2}\Delta\theta\hat{e}\times\vec{x}
$$
My question:
How did they get from $B$ to $B^{-1}$?
I need to understand this because I am trying to implement a fifth order spline, so I need to solve a similar but much complicated equation.
I did manage to find the explicit matrix form for $B(\hat{e}, \Delta\theta)$, by u\sing the Identities:
$$
(\hat{e}\times\vec{x})\times\hat{e} = (\hat{e}\cdot\hat{e})\vec{x}-(\vec{x}\cdot\hat{e})\hat{e} = \vec{x}-(\vec{x}\cdot\hat{e})\hat{e}
\\
(\hat{e}\times\vec{x})\times\hat{e} = -\hat{e}\times(\hat{e}\times\vec{x})
\\
\hat{e}\times\vec{x} = [e]_\times\vec{x}
$$
such that:
$$
B(\hat{e}, \Delta\theta)\cdot\vec{x} = (\vec{x}\cdot\hat{e})\hat{e}+\frac{\sin\Delta\theta}{\Delta\theta}(\hat{e}\times\vec{x})\times\hat{e}-\frac{1-\cos\Delta\theta}{\Delta\theta}\hat{e}\times\vec{x}
\\
=\vec{x}-(\hat{e}\times\vec{x})\times\hat{e}+\frac{\sin\Delta\theta}{\Delta\theta}(\hat{e}\times\vec{x})\times\hat{e}-\frac{1-\cos\Delta\theta}{\Delta\theta}\hat{e}\times\vec{x}
\\
=\vec{x}+\left(\frac{\sin\Delta\theta}{\Delta\theta}-1\right)(\hat{e}\times\vec{x})\times\hat{e}-\frac{1-\cos\Delta\theta}{\Delta\theta}\hat{e}\times\vec{x}
\\
=\vec{x}-\left(\frac{\sin\Delta\theta}{\Delta\theta}-1\right)\hat{e}\times(\hat{e}\times\vec{x})-\frac{1-\cos\Delta\theta}{\Delta\theta}\hat{e}\times\vec{x}
\\
=\left(I-\left(\frac{\sin\Delta\theta}{\Delta\theta}-1\right)[e]_\times[e]_\times-\frac{1-\cos\Delta\theta}{\Delta\theta}[e]_\times\right)\cdot\vec{x}
$$
So:
$$
B = I-\left(\frac{\sin\Delta\theta}{\Delta\theta}-1\right)[e]_\times[e]_\times-\frac{1-\cos\Delta\theta}{\Delta\theta}[e]_\times
$$
And similarly it can be shown that:
$$
B^{-1} = I-\left(\frac{\Delta\theta \sin\Delta\theta}{2(1-\cos\Delta\theta)}-1\right)[e]_\times[e]_\times+\frac{1}{2}\Delta\theta[e]_\times
$$
What is the way to get $B^{-1}$ from $B$?
The article can be found in: https://qspline.sourceforge.net/qspline.pdf and I'm talking about equations (23)-(26)

Just compute $B\cdot B^{-1}$ and check that this is the identity?

I don't want to check it, I want to know how to get $B^{-1}$ if $B$ is in this form.

Sometimes mathematicians simply imagine a possible solution, for example $\alpha I+\beta [e]\times + \gamma [e]\times[e]_\times$ and by multiplying matrices try to determine $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$. If they succeed in this, they have found the inverse matrix, given its uniqueness

Given the matrix acting on $x$ as
$$
Bx=(x\cdot e)e+S(e\times x)\times e-Ce\times x
$$
where
$$
S=\frac{\sin\Delta\theta}{\Delta\theta}, \qquad C=\frac{1-\cos\Delta\theta}{\Delta\theta}
$$
and with $|e|=1$, we can define
$$
Wx=e\times x
$$
and so
$$
W^2x=e\times(e\times x)=-e^2x+(e\cdot x)e=-Ix+(e\cdot x)e
$$
then
$$
(x\cdot e)e=(I+W^2)x
$$
then $B$ can be written
$$
B=I-CW-(S-1)W^2
$$
Also note that
$$
W^3x=W(W^2x)=W[-x+(e\cdot x)e]=-Wx+(e\cdot x)(e\times e) = -Wx
$$
and moreover $W^4=-W^2$.
Now let's define
$$
A=\alpha I+\beta W+\gamma W^2
$$
and perform the multiplication
\begin{align*}
AB&=(\alpha I+\beta W+\gamma W^2)(I-CW-(S-1)W^2)\\
  &=\alpha I-\alpha C W-\alpha (S-1)W^2\\
  &+\beta W-\beta C W^2-\beta (S-1)W^3\\
  &+\gamma W^2-\gamma C W^3-\gamma (S-1)W^4\\
  &=\alpha I+(\beta S+\gamma C-\alpha C)W+(-\beta C+\gamma S-\alpha(S-1))W^2
\end{align*}
If $A$ is the inverse of $B$, then $\alpha = 1$ and
\begin{align}
&+\beta S+\gamma C=C\\ 
&-\beta C+\gamma S=S-1
\end{align}
from which
\begin{align}
\beta &= \frac{C}{C^2+S^2}=\frac{1}{2}\Delta\theta \\
\gamma &= 1-\frac{S}{C^2+S^2}=1-\frac{\Delta\theta\sin\Delta\theta}{2(1-\cos\Delta\theta)}
\end{align}

Nice! thank you very much
